# Janrain contacts

Tags: contacts, janrain

I am using janrain to log onto site and also to pull contacts the users facebook, gmail, etc. accounts.  As it is now it will only pull in contacts from the logged in account.  Is there a way to pull in contacts from their other accounts.  For example if they are logged using their facebook account, is it possible to also pull contacts from their gmail account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a user has only ever authenticated to your site using Facebook, you would not have access to their Google contacts... only what's returned from the API by Facebook.